# MVC5: Cannot Reference Scripts folder from within EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an editor template which cannot reference anything from the scripts folder. If I place the same reference in my layout page it works perfectly:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js")"></script>
```

This works in my layout page but does not load in my Editor Template page.

Edit: Google Developer tools show 404 (Not Found). The file is in the correct location as it can be referenced from my layout Page.

Comment: What happens? What do you see in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body element of your layout page you need to have this code somewhere like this below:

> ```
> <body> ... @Html.RenderScripts() </body>
> ```

and reference your script in your editor template like below:

> ```
> @Html.Script(
>     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js")"></script>
> )
> ```

here is the alternative:

> ```
> <body> ... @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) </body>
> ```

and on your template :

> ```
>  @section scripts {
>   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js")"></script>
>  }
> ```